# Parse C# string to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime, format

I have a string like this:
250920111414

I want to create a DateTime object from that string. As of now, I use substring and do it like this:

```
string date = 250920111414;

int year = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(4, 4));
int month = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(2, 2));
...
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day ...);
```

Is it possible to use string format, to do the same, without substring?

Comment: Even if it were, I don't think you'd gain anything - this looks like an entirely reasonable and readable approach.

Comment: @JeremyMcGee I dont find it that readable actually, i'd prefer Jons approach

Comment: It's readable for me, but were several people on the project.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Absolutely. Guessing the format from your string, you can use [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

```
string format = "ddMMyyyyHHmm";

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx):

```
DateTime dt;
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, format, 
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

The latter call will simply return `false` on parse failure, instead of throwing an exception - if you may have bad data which shouldn't cause the overall task to fail (e.g. it's user input, and you just want to prompt them) then this is a better call to use.

EDIT: For more details about the format string details, see ["Custom Date and Time Format Strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: Do you really remember all those simple but useful solutions by heart or you have a big big big dictionary near your hand? :)

Comment: @Praetor12: For basics like DateTime.ParseExact I remember the method names, but sometimes get the parameters wrong - as I did here, first time :)

Comment: Jon Skeet is simply awesome! Sometimes I feel like having a +1000 button as well.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I told not about methods names, but about format strings. In C# there are so many "formats". May be there is a total list of them. Msdn has only sparse examples in different articles :(

Comment: @Praetor12: Ah, that wasn't clear from your previous comment. I'm pretty familiar with the format strings, especially as I'm currently implementing text parsing/formatting for Noda Time. But in terms of MSDN, look at "Custom Date and Time Format Strings" - I'll add a link in the answer.

Comment: Sometimes stackoverflow gives me that warm & cozy feeling. Like when I need to find info on reversing a custom DateTime.ToString() and I know that Jon Skeet will have answered it. And he did...

Comment: How do you handle this problem adding milliseconds/timezone to the end? I can't get ParseExact to do this.

Comment: @Chazt3n: Well for milliseconds you just use `fff` or `FFF` depending on exactly what you want. For "time zone" you'd need to be more precise about exactly what you mean - a time zone or an offset? Have you read the "custom date and time format strings" page I link to in the answer?

Comment: I did, and it still didn't work! It was an issue in LinqPad, and by creating a new file and copy/pasting the old code, it magically worked. Thank you and I should have caught on sooner.

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
                  date, 
                  "ddMMyyyyHHmm",
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string iDate = "05/05/2005";
DateTime oDate = Convert.ToDateTime(iDate);
DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(iString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt",null);
```

[DateTime Formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZEsc.png)