# C# string to DateTime conversion

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse C# string to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580809/parse-c-sharp-string-to-datetime)

I am facing a problem while converting string to DateTime.

I have the datetime string as

```
20120104073010.221-0700
```

I want to parse it to get `DateTime` object. Another thing, i am not sure if a `.` occures or not in the milliseconds part.

Is there any general way to parse such strings?

Comment: question has been asked zillions of times here in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580809/parse-c-sharp-string-to-datetime

Comment: In that *particular* case, it might be worth handling the core time, the optional millis, and the timezone separately. I'd whack it into 3 pieces, personally. The core part is as Davide mentions; the rest is different, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at the `DateTime.ParseExact` method, which would allow you to specify a format string of the form `"yyyyMMddHHmmss.fffzzz"`. This format string should handle the datetime string you have.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [custom Date and Time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) with `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact`.

Your date/time string looks like this format:

```
"yyyyMMddHHmmss.fffK"

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20120104073010.221-0700", 
                                  "yyyyMMddHHmmss.fffK",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`ParseExact` will throw an exception if it fails, so you may want to use `TryParseExact` that would return `false` on failing instead of throwing.