# How to use more than one Operator in an If Statement using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use multiple operators like =, >, && in my if statement.  I only want to send the email when this condition is true  if (strAuthReqDate == null && strDate < strExpectedSubDate).  So i think my "less than operator" is wrong pls let me know what i am doing wrong here.  thanks

Here is my code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("chkItem");
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        // string strID = gr.Cells[0].Text;
        string strExpectedSubDate = gr.Cells[3].Text;
        string strAuthReqDate = gr.Cells[8].Text;
        string strDate = Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now);
        if (strAuthReqDate == null && strDate < strExpectedSubDate)
        {
            send email();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: It seems to be fine. What is the problem body?

Comment: You are doing a string comparison, not a date comparison.  What format do you expect the `strExpectedSubDate` to be in?

Comment: both fields are date fields. can you show me Mohamed some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this code to compare dates

```
DateTime strExpectedSubDate = DateTime.ParseExact(gr.Cells[3].Text, dateformat);
DateTime strAuthReqDate = DateTime.ParseExact(gr.Cells[8].Text, dateformat);
DateTime strDate = System.DateTime.Now;
if (strAuthReqDate == null && strDate < strExpectedSubDate)
{
}
```

Comment: i am getting an error and i think need to get rid off time portion in my date.  It is showing both the date and the time in the field so how can i only show the Date because the strExpectedSubDate shows only the Date.  thanks

Comment: To help You show only short date in grid I need to see the code where you add records to grid. In general you need set dateformat somewhere.

Comment: Also take a look at answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580809/parse-c-sharp-string-to-datetime as emartel advised you.

Answer (score 2):

First, `Cells[i].Text` is never null, so you should use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpce` or even better,  try to cast it to a `DateTime` instead.

You cannot compare strings and expect that they are treated like DateTimes, C# is not VB6. So convert them to Datetimes first:

```
DateTime ExpectedSubDate;
string strExpectedSubDate = gr.Cells[3].Text;
if(DateTime.TryParse(strExpectedSubDate, out ExpectedSubDate))
{
    DateTime AuthReqDate;
    string strAuthReqDate = gr.Cells[8].Text;
    if(!DateTime.TryParse(strAuthReqDate, out AuthReqDate))
    {
        if(DateTime.Now < ExpectedSubDate)
        {
            SendMail();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code compares textual dates, not actual dates. You need to compare DateTime objects for it to work like you expect!

Comment: so do i need to change it like this:  DateTime strExpectedSubDate = gr.Cells[3].Text;
                    DateTime strAuthReqDate = gr.Cells[8].Text;

Comment: You will need to convert your text, see this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580809/parse-c-sharp-string-to-datetime

Answer (score 1):

It's because strDate and strExpectedSubDate are strings. So you can't compare them using less than operator