# C# custom time format

Tags: c#, format, timespan

Subtraction two time format ,

```
string _time_One = "08:30" ;
string _time_Two = "08:35" ;

string _timeInterval = ( DateTime.Parse(_time_One) - DateTime.Parse(_time_Two) ).Minutes.ToString();
```

It give me the result `5` , but I want to show likes this format `00:05`.
Kindly show me how to format it . Thanks in advance !

Comment: Kindly show that you understand the problem and what you have tried to resolve it. See [MSDN: TimeSpan.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse C# string to DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580809/parse-c-sharp-string-to-datetime)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a TimeSpan to a formatted string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842057/how-do-i-convert-a-timespan-to-a-formatted-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lloyd is right here, but to clarify this for your case:

```
string _time_One = "08:30" ;
string _time_Two = "08:35" ;

TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Parse(_time_One) - DateTime.Parse(_time_Two);
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Time: {0:00}:{1:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes));
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Subtracting two `DateTime` gives you a `TimeSpan` which has it's own formatting support using the `ToString` method.

For example:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime later = now.AddMinutes(10);
TimeSpan span = later - now;

string result = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

You can read more here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51.aspx).

Comment: @LIoyd ,have you test your code ? (Input string was not in a correct format.)

Comment: @zey Testing, what's that? :P I forgot to escape the `:`, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string _time_One = "08:30";
string _time_Two = "08:35";
var span = (DateTime.Parse(_time_One) - DateTime.Parse(_time_Two));
string _timeInterval = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm}", span);
```

For reference: [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
string _time_One = "08:30";
string _time_Two = "08:35";

string _timeInterval = (DateTime.Parse(_time_One) - DateTime.Parse(_time_Two)).Duration().ToString();
```

result=>00:05:00